# Will Kafka group rebalance causes less and less consumers alive?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If Kafka consumers consume messages in sync mode, but their dependent downstream service is broken(eg. cannot connect to DB). Kafka coordinator keeps triggering group rebalance, will all the consumers be dead in the end?

Comment: Are you talking about Kafka Connect, or some manual consumer process you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as consumer is responding for heart beat intervals, Kafka does not do the re-balancing. If suppose you consumer failed to respond for heart beat to zookeeper then Kafka assume the consumer is dead and perform re balancing. it is based on couple of properties [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

**heartbeat.interval.ms**

> The expected time between heartbeats to the consumer coordinator when using Kafka's group management facilities. Heartbeats are used to ensure that the consumer's session stays active and to facilitate rebalancing when new consumers join or leave the group. The value must be set lower than session.timeout.ms, but typically should be set no higher than 1/3 of that value. It can be adjusted even lower to control the expected time for normal rebalances.

**session.timeout.ms**

> The timeout used to detect consumer failures when using Kafka's group management facility. The consumer sends periodic heartbeats to indicate its liveness to the broker. If no heartbeats are received by the broker before the expiration of this session timeout, then the broker will remove this consumer from the group and initiate a rebalance. Note that the value must be in the allowable range as configured in the broker configuration by group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms

**zookeeper.session.timeout.ms**

> ZooKeeper session timeout. If the consumer fails to heartbeat to ZooKeeper for this period of time it is considered dead and a rebalance will occur.

Comment: I mean my consumers will keep blocking because of DB failure.So the next poll request will not be sent,and group rebalance occurs.After group rebalancing, the DB is still in abnormal status.So it results to group rebalancing again and again.Im wondering wether all Kafka consumers will die in the end?

Comment: No there is no end for rebalancing, if consumers are failing it will continue the rebalancing, why don't you handle the DB failure exceptions?

Comment: What if catching exception and invoking pause method, When dB is well, then invoking resume method?

Comment: the only way to pause the thread is `sleep()` when the consumer thread is in sleep mode it will not responded for heart beat intervals, then again re balance will take place, suggested way DB should be up, or i'm not sure you can explicitly stop all consumer threads.

Comment: KafkaConsumer has both pause and resume methods.

Comment: yes just now i checked then you can use happily https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html